# How to get namespace details for ecs

Tags: python, api, amazon-ecs

I want to print namespaces for my ecs-client. When I am using print(client.user_info.whoami()) I am getting the output. But when I am executing the below code I am getting attribute error.

```
from ecsclient.client import Client
from ecsclient.common.multitenancy import namespace

client = Client('3',
                username='root',
                password='password',
                token_endpoint='https://abc.xyz.com:4443/login',
                ecs_endpoint='https://abc.xyz.com:4443')

print(client.namespace.get_namespaces())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(client.namespace.get_namespaces())
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'get_namespaces'
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `print(client.namespace.get_namespaces())` I used `print(client.namespace.list())` and got the list of namespaces